# Using C#, how can I create invisible property on listbox item and access it?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listbox

I'm using C# Windows Forms, and I have created a listbox and I want to create a value within each individual item in this listbox that is not visible. So to do this I have choosen to use the Display Member. There is only one problem. The name of the item I create that is visible to the user, in the listBox, is not the DisplayMember in the code which is "Item Name". Instead the name of the Item I create appears as "Doc_Engine.PersonalMessageSystemForm+SomeData".

Here is my first code:

```
//Create an item in the listBox1.
List<SomeData> data = new List<SomeData>();
data.Add(new SomeData() { Value = 1, Text = "Hidden Text" });
listBox1.DataSource = data;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Item Name";
```

And here is my second code:

```
//A class that contains two required strings.
public class SomeData
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
```

[Click here to see a picture of my ListBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STbki.jpg)

I want the name of my Item in the listbox to be "Item Name". Not "Doc_Engine.PersonalMessageSystemForm+SomeData".

Update: I might use the Tag property instead. But when I do this, the same thing happens. The name of the item does not turn out as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SomeData` class doesn't have a member called `Item Name`.  It has two members: `Value` and `Text`. So, per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspxv) you get the result of calling `ToString` instead:

> If the specified property does not exist on the object or the value of DisplayMember is an empty string (""), the results of the object's ToString method are displayed instead.

Change it to `Value` or `Text` or add some other property to hold the value you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

In winforms controls there is a `Tag` property you can set to anything you want and later retrieve. Try using that instead.

Comment: Now the same is happening with the Item name when I use tags.